# Conservar la estructura de los datos

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame donde algunas columnas son de tipo character, otras numericas etc.
Algunas de las columnas tienen 0. Quiero cambiar todos los 0 por NAs

Aplico lo siguiente

```
datos2<-data.frame(sapply(datos, function(x) {ifelse(x==0,NA,x)}))
str(datos2)
```

Y resulta que todas las columnas son ahora de tipo factor.

¿Cómo hago para que datos y datos2 tengan la misma estructura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin tener al objeto `datos` es un poco difícil saber **exactamente** que pasa, pero me parece que el problema es el sapply y las reglas de coerción de estructuras de datos que aplica. Va un ejemplo de lo que podría estar pasando.

```
datos <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 0, 3, 4, NA), 
  b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  c = c("A", "0",  NA, NA, NA))
```

En este caso `datos` tiene una columna numérica, una lógica (a los NA si no están con otro tipo de datos válidos se les asigna el tipo lógico) y una carácter. `R` "adivina" el que tipo de datos, ya sabemos que es [débilmente tipado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte). Como estoy usando R>4.0, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` por defecto, de lo contrario a `c` le asignaría la clase `factor`. Creo que da igual a efectos del problema.

```
datos2 <- data.frame(sapply(datos, function(x) {ifelse(x==0,NA,x)}))
datos2

   a    b    c
<NA> <NA>    A
<NA> <NA> <NA>
   3 <NA> <NA>
   4 <NA> <NA>
<NA> <NA> <NA>

sapply(datos2, class)

          a           b           c 
"character" "character" "character"
```

En efecto, todas son de la clase carácter, si esto fuera R<4.0 serían factores, pero da igual para este problema. ¿Por qué? Porque `sapply()`, que es un peligro aplicando coerciones a los datos. Es difícil saber con precisión que clase nos va a regresar `sapply()`. En este caso lo que hace es pasar la función `ifelse()` en cada columna de `datos` y regresar el resultado en una **matriz**, que luego se coerciona a data.frame. El punto es que las matrices no soportan columnas de diferentes tipo, entonces obliga a que los datos se expresen en el tipo más básico. Como tengo una columna con caracteres lo que hace es bajar a todas las demás al nivel carácter, que tiene mayor generalidad. Es decir, puedo expresar número como caracteres, pero no caracteres como números.

## Solución

Si `datos` debería contener solo numéricas ahí está el problema. Si está bien que sea una combinación de números y letras entonces la mejor alternativa es `lapply()` en lugar de `sapply()`. `lapply()` **siempre** regresa una lista y en una lista **sí** puede haber elementos heterogéneos, entonces cada columna conserva sus atributos.

```
datos2 <- data.frame(lapply(datos, function(x) {ifelse(x==0,NA,x)}))

sapply(dato2, class)
        a           b           c 
"numeric"   "logical" "character"
```

Alternativamente:

```
datos[] <-  lapply(datos, function(x) {ifelse(x==0,NA,x)})
```

También funciona. Al poner `datos[]` del lado izquierdo `R` trata de conservar todos los atributos que puede en la asignación, así que lo mantiene como `data.frame`.

## Conclusión

`R` es débilmente tipado, eso facilita muchas cosas, pero genera este tipo de inconsistencias en los resultados. Adivinar el ouput de `sapply()` es una lotería y hay que usarla con mucho cuidado. Si estás trabajando con listas, incluyendo data.frame, es más seguro usar `lapply()` y si es necesario simplificar el resultado en un paso posterior.